# How Kafka Brokers find each other?

Tags: apache-kafka

When we start kafka broker, it automatically finds other brokers and starts talking to them. How do kafka brokers find each other's FQDN/IP address? Is it something Zookeeper gives and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, this data is stored in zookeeper.

get /brokers/ids/0

{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"SSL":"SSL"},"endpoints":["SSL://localhost:9093"],"jmx_port":-1,"host":null,"timestamp":"1597069927841","port":-1,"version":4}